# F# open source projects

Tags: open-source, f#

I'm looking for some open source F# projects to learn from. 
Something not snippets but full projects that are good representatives of F# features (i.e. pattern matching, discriminated unions, etc).

My objective are mainly to see how all the features fit together, how the project is organized and how the problems are tackled from a functional perspective.

Comment: https://github.com/fsprojects

Answer (score 43):

List of Open Source F# Projects (Compiled):

- [A Mathematical Application in F# that integrates Autocad via .NET](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/11/a-mathematical-.html)
- [Game Development Tutorials](http://code.google.com/p/fs-gamedev/)
- [FsUnit](https://github.com/fsharp/fsunit)
- [Storm](http://www.codeplex.com/storm) (a tool for testing Web Services)
- [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) - F# Parser Combinator Library
- [DownloadStockPrices](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DownloadStockPrices) - Written in F#
- [Truskill](http://blogs.technet.com/apg/archive/2008/04/05/trueskill-through-time.aspx) - Xbox Live Player Rater (Written in F#)
- [F# Collective Intelligence Implementation](http://github.com/robertpi/fscollintelli/tree/master)
- [NDjango](http://ndjango.org)
- [BistroFS - F# web framework](http://bistrofs.codeplex.com/)
- [VsVim - Vim Emulation for Visual Studio](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim)

Comment: I can't correct your entry but the DownloadStockPrices link is broken.

Comment: @zvolkov No worries. However, it is in line with the founders' vision for Stack Overflow (See Joel's many comments on the subject).

Comment: strange, but sources of Calculator (@googlecode) is closed.

Answer (score 11):

[FsCheck](http://www.codeplex.com/fscheck), a specification-based testing framework.

[VCC](http://vcc.codeplex.com/), static analysis of C programs (by MS research)

[VSLab](http://vslab.codeplex.com/), a mathematica/matlab like environment in visual studio

Answer (score 5):

Found another one:

[Storm](http://www.codeplex.com/storm): a tool for testing web services

Answer (score 4):

[BistroFS](http://bistrofs.codeplex.com/) - a web framework for F#

Answer (score 4):

Frack -- Functional Rack -- is an implementation of OWIN (Open Web Interface for .NET), which has a similar intent as the Python WSGI and JSGI specifications. Frack is similar in implementation to Rack and Jack and owes a lot to those projects.

https://github.com/panesofglass/frank

Answer (score 3):

[Searching on google code](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:fsharp) I found:

- a [calculator](http://code.google.com/p/fssamples/)
- [game dev tutorials](http://code.google.com/p/fs-gamedev/)
- [FsUnit](http://code.google.com/p/fsunit/) (a specification framework)

Comment: You should have compiled all your answers into one answer.

Comment: No. Different projects generate different levels of interest so the most interesting or representative project should be the most voted.

Comment: @Mausch : Stack Overflow is not meant to be used as a polling mechanism. Voters often downvote authors that post multiple answers, simply because they appear to be vote-whoring.

Comment: Especially since your question is 1) not a wiki, and 2) doesn't ask that question.

Comment: I don't agree with your POV and I don't care too much about rep, if you look at my profile you'll see that I've been answering lots of obscure questions that don't get much votes. And I *did* ask for representative projects. And see the dates, nobody answered and it took me 6 days to find something.

Comment: Anyway just to keep you happy I made this question and all my answers here wiki.

Answer (score 3):

[FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) - A Parser Combinator Library for F#

Answer (score 3):

[DownloadStockPrices](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DownloadStockPrices):

> Downloads stock prices, dividends and
> splits from Yahoo historical quotes.
> It also modify them to make them as
> happened and adjust them to calculate
> adjusted prices. There is also a .NET
> component that can be reused from
> C#/VB.NET. It is written in F# but it
> can be used from whatever .NET
> language.
>
> Link to blog posts is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2008/09/26/downloading-stock-prices-in-f-part-v-adjusting-historical-data.aspx):
>
> It has been written with the F#
> September 2008 CTP.
>
> The solution is composed by:
>
> - a library to perform the dowload
> - a test project using xUnit (but you have to download xUnit and reference
>   it in the Tests project to run it)
> - a simple Console based driver
> - a start of a graphical UI app using the library (called Bob)

Comment: "a start of a graphical UI app using the library (called Bob)" <-- Is this for real? Another Microsoft Bob? I love it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Wing Beats](http://wingbeats.codeplex.com/) can be of interest?

The project is less than a year old, and we are only two contributors so far, but I believe there are interesting stuff to check out.

We want others to join, or at least check it out and give it a try.

Comment: Looks good, have you seen #light? http://sharplight.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've looked at it briefly and it seems interesting. I also find the principles Sadek talks about to be sound.

It hasn't been updated lately though.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not sure about the licensing...
Microsoft's TrueSkill system (which rates players in XBox360 live gaming)
has published some source code.

http://blogs.technet.com/apg/archive/2008/04/05/trueskill-through-time.aspx

Comment: cool! it contains a DAL in F# :)

Answer (score 2):

Robert Pickering has put an F# project focused on [Collective Intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_intelligence) similar to Toby Segaran's book ["Collective Intelligence"](http://books.google.com/books?id=fEsZ3Ey-Hq4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Collective+INtelligence&ei=fzPdSb3vNYKqzgTE_OTUDg) ( demonstrated therein via python ) on github:

[fscollintelli](http://github.com/robertpi/fscollintelli/tree/master)

Answer (score 2):

I just created a spot for my open source project [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/), an F# library for writing unit test assertions as F# quoted expressions. It's a good example for learning about recursively processing and rebuilding quotations using active patterns and pattern matching, mixing object oriented and functional code (it uses .NET Reflection heavily), and writing unit tests using xUnit.net and... the library itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing a visual object tree inspector for FSI called [FsEye](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/). It demonstrates WinForms development in F# including using `async` to perform non-blocking GUI updates and parallel computations. Object trees are modeled using Discriminant Unions and Records. `Lazy` values and sequence expressions are used for on-demand loading of (infinite depth) sub-trees. Active Patterns are used to smooth out working with non-generic `TreeViewNodes`.

Answer (score 1):

[YaccConstructor](http://code.google.com/p/recursive-ascent/) - modular tool for grammars processing and parsers construction.