# Open source projects written in a functional programming language

Tags: open-source, functional-programming

Are there any open source projects out there that are written in a functional programming language and that people can contribute on? I am trying to increase my area of expertise to a functional programming language and I think contributing to a project might be the way to go. Maybe some OCaml  or Lisp projects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019549/good-projects-to-learn-ocaml-and-f

Answer (score 5):

[MLdonkey](http://www.mldonkey.org/) is written in OCaml.

Of course various libraries for functional languages are also generally written in the respective language. So you can find a lot of projects on the language's "library hub". For example for haskell there's [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/), which is full of open source haskell projects.

Answer (score 5):

SourceForge's projects written on:

[OCaml](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/?&fq%5B%5D=trove%3A454) (187)

[Lisp](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/?&fq%5B%5D=trove%3A170) (436)

[Common Lisp](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/?&fq%5B%5D=trove%3A540) (111)

[Erlang](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/?&fq%5B%5D=trove%3A264) (110)

Answer (score 3):

http://github.com/languages/OCaml

http://github.com/languages/Common%20Lisp

http://github.com/languages/Erlang

Answer (score 3):

A few of the popular NoSQL databases are written in Erlang (if you consider that to be a functional language, that is), including [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/index.html) and [Riak](http://riak.basho.com/). Both are open-source, and both still under active development.

Answer (score 2):

Most of EMACS is written in elisp.

Comment: Also the various 3rd party modes and add-ons for emacs.

Comment: -1, Emacs is not written in a functional style. See the comments here: http://goo.gl/S2Vj

Answer (score 0):

[Ejabberd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejabberd) written by Erlang seems to be a chat server that is mature and active.(as @skaffman said, if you consider Erlang as a functional programming language).