# Functional dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, functional-programming

When writing object-oriented software, I use dependency injection a lot:

- to compose together high-level functionality from lower-level capabilities: my account management service uses repositories and validation services rather than implementing them itself.
- to isolate components from their dependencies: my account management service uses its dependencies through interfaces, so that I can swap implementations, mock for unit testing and so on.

What patterns exist in functional programming languages to achieve these goals?

*edit:* a commenter rightly asks: "what about just passing round functions?". I think that the following comment about function grouping hits the nail on the head - a service is a collection of functions with a shared set of dependencies that I can handle as an atomic group.

In Clojure  it seems like protocols solve this nicely, but I was really wondering how the problem is solved more generally...

Comment: You mean other than passing around functions? Why would that not meet your needs?

Comment: @marcin Services is not just functions. Actually they are often composed from many functions with a coordinated (in some sense) behavior.

Comment: @CheatEx they *are* functions (which in turn may be composed of other, smaller functions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decomposition (modularity) in functional languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774224/decomposition-modularity-in-functional-languages)

Comment: @Mauricio it is not so evident for me. For example lets look at the twitter API. There is a lot of methods, which one want to use in some common way (say with already provided authentication). Question: how can you represent all different methods as a one function? Yes, it is possible to pass a symbol, identifying a method and get a function which represents that method, but this is what we have OO-approach(dynamically typed BTW), don't we?

Comment: @CheatEx each twitter API method could be mapped to a function. All these functions can be grouped in a module (both Haskell and ML languages offer modules, for example). No need for objects there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the small scale, things like currying and functions-as-parameters cut down the need for module dependencies. At a larger scale, things like Standard ML functors are very useful for this purpose. Racket has a system called units that does a good job on this too.

Comment: jacobm,  I'm intrigued at how functors are useful for managing dependencies on a larger scale.  Could you point us to an example of how this would work?

Answer (score 8):

Some time ago I've read a [post](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/03/functional-dependency-injection.html) describing how dependency injection can be seen as currying in functional programming. I think it's very interesting, and it gives a good perspective on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a little library which I found helpful for DI in a functional-inspired (JavaScript) environment, it's nothing special, just a bit method I like.