# Opensource F# project with idiomatic code

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm learning F# and I would like to find some medium size opensource project written in idiomatic F# for further learning.
Can ayone recommend some project?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: [WebSharper](http://websharper.com/) is a good bet (I haven't looked at the code, but the author is a bright guy), but this question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I hope my open source F# offerings are idiomatic! Unquote: http://code.google.com/p/unquote/, FsEye: http://code.google.com/p/fseye/, and NL, http://code.google.com/p/nl-compiler/ (this one has no public releases and is more experimental).

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383848/f-open-source-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a single good idiomatic open-source project to look at, but here is a couple of links. First of all, there is a number of things from F# itself that are worth exploring:

- The [F# compiler and core libraries](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core) are open-source and worth checking out. The compiler is quite difficult, but some of the libraries are good example of nice F# code.
- The [F# PowerPack](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack) is also open-source and implements some interesting types (like matrix, vector and some immutable collections)

Some very nice (commented!) and reasonably sized F# projects include:

- [Cellz](http://cellz.codeplex.com/) - an Excel-like spreadsheet application written using Silverlight. It has parser for simple expressions and nice evaluation engine that handles dependencies between cells.
- [TickSpeck](http://tickspec.codeplex.com/) - a framework for behaviour driven development (BDD) written in F#
  (If you're interested in development methodologies, then this might interest you)
- [F# binding for MonoDevelop](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding) - is a well commented (I believe :-)) but reasonably small project that implements F# binding for MD. It uses `MailboxProcessor` (aka "agents") in an interesting way.
- Antoher big F# open-source project is [FSharpX](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) - a package of various F# libraries - however I would not recommend it as *idiomatic* F# code. It takes lot of ideas and some syntax from Haskell, which is not really idiomatic in F#, but it contains many interesting and useful parts.

Aside from projects, if you want to learn how to write idiomatic F# code, then there is an excellent [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFIQFjAA&url=http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf&ei=Q1XST4zwGcjU8QOI7rWeAw&usg=AFQjCNG_EV9hAPks_Ll-Av-5NTX9TsqrJw&sig2=h2pvEUA9RlvxJf99dH_iJg) document from the F# team.

Comment: You beat me to it on the F# Powerpack suggestion.